How to show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent without using the uniqueness of the MGF
Let $(X, Y)$ be an absolutely continuous random vector and $M_{X, Y}$ be the bivariate moment generating function of $(X, Y)$.
I want to show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if
$$M_{X, Y}\left(t_1, t_2\right) = M_X\left(t_1\right)M_Y\left(t_2\right),$$
provided that $t_1$ and $t_2$ are in some neighbourhood of $0$.
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then clearly the result holds.
If $M_{X, Y}\left(t_1, t_2\right) = M_X\left(t_1\right)M_Y\left(t_2\right)$ then $E\left(e^{t_1 X + t_2 Y}\right) = E\left(e^{t_1 X}\right)E\left(e^{t_2 Y}\right)$, so
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{t_1 x + t_2 y}f_{X, Y}(x, y) dy dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{t_1 x}f_X(x) dx \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{t_2 y}f_Y(y) dy = \\$$
$$= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{t_1 x + t_2 y} f_X(x)f_Y(y) dy dx.$$
Now, my question: how could I justify that $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ without using that the bivariate MGF is unique?
